# spotify api, how to make a playlist without user id

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, api, spotify

I am learning to implement the spotify api, and I found that trackset is no longer supported. However, I still want to use the concept of a temporary playlist without a user id, especially because I'm using client credentials to get my access token.

Is there any way i can create a temporary playlist that works just like trackset with the spotify play button? 
thanks!